# Custom Pricing based on anonymous customer input

Tags: commerce

Hi gurus and fellows,

I am a newbie at DrupalCommerce, though I have been designing website for a while using Drupal.

For our new project, we need to provide some custom pricing rules, based on user input. **Anomymous** user fills in a form, and, based on his input, we compute some special 'discount' (sort of).  Let me emphasize that user is not connected (registered), and its data is kept in session only.

As far as I know, we need to set up some "Pricing Rules", but to tackle my problem, I can only see "User has role" / "User is blocked" in the possible conditions, which address only logged-on users.

How you would you do that ? 
Do I need to write up a custom rule ?

Any hints much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This discussion might help you: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1251
If you can reconsider Commerce, this is the same module for Ubercart:
http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price/
It's not stable for D7 though.

Answer (score 0):

User has role can indeed be used to setup a rule for Anomymous user, see the image:

[image: Screen shot]